# How do I caulk where a caulk tube won't fit?

Tags: tools, caulking

I've got some door moldings that are about 1 inch from the adjacent wall. A caulk gun won't begin to get in there, and pivoting the caulk tube up so it's nearly parallel to both walls still doesn't get the tip close enough to the gap.

How should I apply a caulk bead in this situation? Any good tricks, clever tools, or "this worked well enough for me"?

Rough illustration of the situation:

[image: illustration]
<sub>(source: [CoSketch.com](http://CoSketch.com/SavedImages/ppH0F7pw.png))</sub>

Comment: Do you mean the casings are sitting one inch out from the wall? That the jambs were much wider than the thickness of the walls?

Comment: Or do you mean that the wall the casing sits on is only 1 inch wide (beyond the casing) before it hits an inside corner?

Comment: @bib The second. I added a illustration in an edit to the question that I hope clarifies things.

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman  It does, immensely.  Suddenly the question makes sense.  +1.

Comment: Use your finger. Caulk dries and falls of easily. Yea, its messy but it gets the job done :)

Comment: @ppumkin Tried that, but what a mess. Caulk smears out all over the wall and you end up having to repaint everything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to DA01's suggestion, there are also smaller tubes of [caulk](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-202261807/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=caulk&storeId=10051) that may be thin/small enough to angle into the casing corner. More costly, but you only need a little (if it fits).

[image: caulk]

Comment: I've always seen the big, solid tubes. A toothpaste tube of caulk would be just the thing. I'll pick one of these up the next time I'm out acquiring more widgets.

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman There are new, mini-sized widgets, for those occasions when you only have 1 inch between widget sender and widget receiver.

Answer (score 8):

If it's an interior door, I'd suggest not bothering. If you can't easily get the tube in there, my guess is you can't easily see it, so it's probably moot.

If it's an exterior door, two ideas:

1. remove the trim, apply the caulk, re-apply the trim
2. cut a small bit of surgical hose and attach it to the end of the caulk and use that to apply it.

Comment: The surgical hose is clever. My first thought was a straw, but we had none handy, and I imagined it would just break in the middle or go shooting off to nowhere.

Comment: Try a wide diameter drinking straw, or get a short length of clear plastic tube from any hardware store.